# NIntgrate error inumr

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, numerics

I'm new to Mathematica. I am trying to numerically integrate a function

```
F[B_?NumericQ, r_, A_?NumericQ, β_?NumericQ, η_?NumericQ] := 
  B (1 + r^2/A^2)^(-(3/2) β η)
```

in the following way,

```
ft[f_, r_, k_] := 
  1/(2 π)^(3/2) NIntegrate[(4 π r^2) f Exp[-I k r], {r, -∞, ∞}]

ft[F, r, 10]`
```

I keep getting an error message that says the integrand has evaluated to non-numerical values. What do I do? I thought that including `?NumericQ` should get rid of this problem, but it has not.

Comment: You do not seem to have assigned numerical values to some of your variables in `F`